# Deploying a Python Automation script in the cloud

Tags: python, cloud

I have a working Python automation program `combine_excel.py`. It accesses a server and extracts excel files and combining them with an automation workflow. Currently, I need to execute this automation manually.

I like to host this program in a cloud/server and activate the script at preset timings and at regular intervals. I like to know if there is any service out there that will allow me to do that. Can I do this on Google Cloud or AWS?

The program will generate an output that I could have it saved into to my Google Drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy/cost-effective way to achieve this could be to use AWS Lambda functions. Lambda functions can be set to trigger at certain time intervals using CRON syntax.

You might need to make some minor adjustments to match some format requirements Lambda has, maybe workout a way to include dependencies if you have any, but everything should be pretty straightforward as there is a lot of information available on the web.

The same can be achieved using Google Cloud Functions.

You could also try Serverless Framework which would take care of the deployment for you, you only need to set it up once.

Another options is to try Zeit it's quite simple to use, and it has a free tier (as the others).

Some useful links:

- https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html
- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python
- https://zeit.co/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/python

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.